# can Exponent CMS work with Nginx as opposed to Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nginx

I'm trying to run a website built with ExponentCMS but my server runs Nginx as the webserver... is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but if I were you, I'd ask myself whether it is worth the hassle of getting it working on an unusual configuration.

The overhead of Apache compared to running PHP apps in FastCGI is much less than most people realize (just looking at top and adding the resident memory consumption of each apache process doesn't cut it).  You can still get many of the benefits of Nginx by setting it up to serve static files and reverse proxy everything else to apache.  Make sure to enable buffering of proxied requests, it will allow apache to move on to the next request while nginx deals with feeding the result back to the client, which makes much more efficient use of the memory apache+php takes up.  Plus, you get to draw on all the experience people have with deploying PHP apps on apache.  I'm using the combo to host wordpress on my VPS

Comment: if the host getting high traffic or frequently digged then it's worth it. but nginx is not that hard anyway... it's very easy actually. i manage to install it for joomla on first try. the only thing need work is translating the htaccess.

Comment: Well we use nginx for django configuration as most of our apps are django/python apps, but a client wanted to host this exponent based website, but we couldn't get it to work with our configuration.

Answer (score 0):

uhh, apache is free, why not just install and run that also?

Answer (score 0):

most php works just fine with nginx.
if you dont need/use .htaccess then all should works just fine out of the box.

if you need/use .htaccess, you need to translate that to nginx.conf
then it will works just fine.